# how to select drop down list based on <p> value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Click form edit has trouble on drop down list

Dropdown list shows first item. I need to select value based on `<p>Professor<p/>`

html

```
<p>Title</p>
<p class='title'>Professor</p>
```

JQuery

```
$('.title').click(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<select class="title" name="title"><option >Please Select</option><option value="Mr">Mr</option><option value="Mrs">Mrs</option><option value="Ms">Ms</option><option value="Miss">Miss</option><option value="Dr">Dr</option><option value="Professor">Professor</option><option value="Sir">Sir</option></select>');
});​
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/U7rAc/3/)

Comment: What is your question? If the problem is that the previous value is not selected, then just edit the string argument in `replaceWith()`, and move the "selected" to the right position. Alternatively, `$('select').val()` should also work after the `replaceWith()`.

Comment: not sure what you're wanting to do here. Are you saying you want a certain value selected by default?

Comment: @StefanMajewsky Majewsky actually the selected value should be based previous value

Comment: maanu: I understood that very well.

Comment: @Phillip Schmidt yes, the selected value should be `<p>` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var theValue = $(this).html();
    $("select.title").val( theValue ).attr('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to select 'professor' by default this will do the trick:

```
$('.title').click(function(){
    var target = $(this);
    var text = target.text();
    var select = $('<select class="title" name="title"><option selected="selected">Please Select</option><option value="Mr">Mr</option><option value="Mrs">Mrs</option><option value="Ms">Ms</option><option value="Miss">Miss</option><option value="Dr">Dr</option><option value="Professor">Professor</option><option value="Sir">Sir</option></select>');
    select.find('option[value="' + text + '"]').prop("selected", true);
    target.replaceWith(select);
});
```

[Fixed jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u8Bux/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/U7rAc/3/):

```
$('.title').click(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<select class="title" name="title"><option selected="selected">Please Select</option><option value="Mr">Mr</option><option value="Mrs">Mrs</option><option value="Ms">Ms</option><option value="Miss">Miss</option><option value="Dr">Dr</option><option value="Professor">Professor</option><option value="Sir">Sir</option></select>');
    $('.title').val($(this).text());
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use an array ?

```
$('.title').on("click", function(){
    var selected = $(this).text();

    var contents = null;
    var options = ['Mr', 'Mrs', 'Ms', 'Miss', 'Dr', 'Professor', 'Sir'];

    for ( i = 0 ; i < options.length ; i++ )
    {
        if ( options[i] == selected )
            contents += '<option value='+ options[i] +' selected="selected">'+ options[i] +'</option>';
        else              
            contents += '<option value='+ options[i] +'>'+ options[i] +'</option>';
    }

    $(this).replaceWith('<select class="title" name="title"><option>Please Select</option>'+ contents +'</select>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ona way to do it:

```
$('.title').click(function(){
    var pVal = this.innerHTML;
    $(this).replaceWith('<select class="title" name="title"><option selected="selected">Please Select</option><option value="Mr">Mr</option><option value="Mrs">Mrs</option><option value="Ms">Ms</option><option value="Miss">Miss</option><option value="Dr">Dr</option><option value="Professor">Professor</option><option value="Sir">Sir</option></select>');
    $('select.title').val(pVal);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U7rAc/6/

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the text of the paragraph that was clicked before you replace the HTML. Then use jQuery to find the select list you've created and set its value.

```
$('.title').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        selected = $this.text();
    $this.replaceWith('<select class="title" name="title"><option selected="selected">Please Select</option><option value="Mr">Mr</option><option value="Mrs">Mrs</option><option value="Ms">Ms</option><option value="Miss">Miss</option><option value="Dr">Dr</option><option value="Professor">Professor</option><option value="Sir">Sir</option></select>');
    $('.title').val(selected);
});​
```

in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U7rAc/5/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to append your `<select>` all at once, I'd do something more like this. That way, you can check for a default option and set the selected attribute on it.

```
$('.title').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $select = $('<select>'),
        defaultValue = $this.text(),
        options = [
            'Please Select',
            'Mr',
            'Mrs',
            'Ms',
            'Miss',
            'Dr',
            'Professor',
            'Sir'
        ];

    $.each(options, function() {
        var $option = $('<option>');
        $option.text(this);
        $option.val(this);
        if (this == defaultValue) {
            $option.attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
        $select.append($option);
    });

    $this.replaceWith($select);
});​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/my6FV/).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. This will convert and select the same value in the option list as that which was clicked on.

```
$('.title').click(function(){
    var selected_item = $(this).html();
    $(this).replaceWith('<select class="title" name="title"><option>Please Select</option><option value="Mr">Mr</option><option value="Mrs">Mrs</option><option value="Ms">Ms</option><option value="Miss">Miss</option><option value="Dr">Dr</option><option value="Professor">Professor</option><option value="Sir">Sir</option></select>');
    $('option:contains("' + selected_item + '")', 'select.title').prop('selected', 'selected');
});​
```